# Word Document Not Responding

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, documents

I am trying to work with a Word Document since many months, but it does not respond most of the time. It opens sometimes, but is very slow and with a few edits it hangs.

After doing some research, I have found out that the document is full of individual tables (*one table on each page, in a 200 page document*) which takes up a lot of memory and Word cannot handle keeping the file open for long. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Computer specs:
Lenovo Thinkpad T490-
Core i5 8365U, 16 GB DDR4, Disk space- 126 GB free, out of 237 GB, Office 365.

Comment: What is the computer model? How much memory (RAM) does it have? Is the disk full by any chance?

Comment: Please edit your question to respond to harrymc's questions. I would add, what is the operating system and version of Word/Office? -------  In addition, it sounds as if you have a poorly set-up document because Word can easily handle thousands of pages. Direct formatting vs. style-based formatting, manual page breaks, floating tables and graphics (instead of in-line) and lots of merged table cells can all contribute to complexity. So can unnecessary section breaks.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon Thanks for your help. Yes, as I have already said, this is a legacy document that I've inherited and it is poorly made - with several tables, atleast one per page and there are 262 pages. Since I know that Word finds it very difficult to handle so many tables, I want to know if there is any alternative to having tables to represent information without compromising on the readability. (Each table is a simple 2 column, 6 row table with some FAQ information)

Comment: Yes, there are several alternatives, but getting to them on an existing document will be a real pain. You could have one or two tables rather than one per page. You can format the text in a table cell to have "page break before" paragraph formatting to force a page break within the table. You could convert the tables to text and edit using tabs and indents. You could try copying all of the document into a new document and pasting using paste special - plain text. If you try doing these things, do them with a copy of the document rather than the original.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesKenyon I will try them out.